# MaterialButton onPressed area clipped when using Fractional Translation

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building an app, and some of my material buttons (customButtonGoToAddPage) float over the navbar. Visualy this looks perfect, but only the part the is not overflowing the header is tappable.

[image]

I have tried moving the custom button into the header widget, and changing the offset to go down rather, but the same issue persisted.

I have a feeling it either has something to do with the clipper I built, or just not using the right widgets for the job.

Still new at this flutter thing, definitely code needs a clean up.

```
eventHeader(_scaffoldKey),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                  child: FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print('Sort By Date');
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.swap_vert)),
                ),
                customButtonGoToAddPage(context, '/event_add'),
              ],
            ),
```

```
// Go To Add Page
Row customButtonGoToAddPage(BuildContext context, String url) {
  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      FractionalTranslation(
        translation: Offset(-0.2, -0.6),
        child: Align(
          child: MaterialButton(
              minWidth: 30.0,
              height: 60,
              textColor: Colors.green[500],
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                size: 30,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(url);
              },
              shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(100.0))),
          alignment: FractionalOffset(0.5, 0.0),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

```
// **** Page Head

ClipPath eventHeader(key) {
  return ClipPath(
    clipper: BottomWaveClipper(),
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: getAppGradient(),
      ),
      height: 130,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0, bottom: 5.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 30, 0, 0),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => {key.currentState.openDrawer()},
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.menu,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  headerTitleRow("EVENTS"),
                  headerSubtitleRow("Need More Control? Create An Event"),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 20, 5, 0),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

```
// Main App Wave Clipper
class BottomWaveClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = new Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height - 0);

    // var firstControlPoint = Offset(size.width / 4, size.height);
    // var firstEndPoint = Offset(size.width / 2.25, size.height - 30.0);
    // path.quadraticBezierTo(firstControlPoint.dx, firstControlPoint.dy,
    //     firstEndPoint.dx, firstEndPoint.dy);

    var secondControlPoint =
        Offset(size.width - (size.width / 2), size.height - 40);
    var secondEndPoint = Offset(size.width, size.height - 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(secondControlPoint.dx, secondControlPoint.dy,
        secondEndPoint.dx, secondEndPoint.dy);

    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height - 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```